# Change field arrangement from the entries page

Tags: control-panel, fieldtypes, ordering

In ExpressionEngine you can rearrange the field types from inside the entry. I was wondering if there was any feature like this in Craft? I've got a lot of different types of entries so it's a pain to jump back and forth between sections and entries to see if the organisation is correct, plus it would just be easier to organise if I can see what the final product would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible with Craft at the moment (2.4). You'll have to use the Field Layout Designer from Settings -> Sections -> {Section} -> {Entry Type} to manage your fields and tabs.

You could always [add a feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests) if you feel this is something that should be included in the core.